# GAE API response no longer showing up in the API explorer

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a cloud endpoints enabled project on Google App Engine. I recently went on to the API explorer to hit the API methods directly and their responses are no longer being displayed on the screen below the "Execute" button like before. It just displays the time to execute. However, the clients who use the API aren't having any problems. Does anyone know why responses are no longer being displayed in the API explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a general issue with the API explorer and Chrome at the moment, nothing specific to endpoints. Using the API explorer in Firefox (or probably any other browser) seems to work for now.

https://code.google.com/p/google-apis-explorer/issues/detail?id=166

Answer (score 0):

Security changed in Chrome (and now has in FF too).
You need to launch Chrome with SSL security disabled for the local domain like (on OSX) this:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --user-data-dir=test --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://localhost:60612
```

Remember to change the port to match your instance address.